# Woocommerce - How to put the short description beneath the product summary?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Using [this](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/) as a visual reference for the hooks. I want to place the short summary at `woocommerce_after_single_product_summary`. I thought I could do that by simply doing something like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt',30);
```

This kind of works, but this places the short summary sort of on the product summary which messes up the whole layout. I've tried playing with priorities but nothing changes. I've also looked up the theme template file, but I can't figure out how to fix it. The theme template file:

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $product;

/**
 * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_product.
 *
 * @hooked wc_print_notices - 10
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product' );

if ( post_password_required() ) {
    echo get_the_password_form(); // WPCS: XSS ok.
    return;
}
?>
<div id="product-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php wc_product_class( '', $product ); ?>>

    <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_images - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary' );
    ?>

    <div class="summary entry-summary ld-product-summary">
        <?php
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_single_product_summary.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_product_summary.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
         * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
    ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product' ); ?>
```

Comment: Issue is related to UI. Try to wrap `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );` by div having few or all classes among `summary entry-summary ld-product-summary`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php

add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_short_description', 25);
function show_short_description() {
    global $post;
    $short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );
    if( !empty($short_description) ) {
        echo $short_description;
    }
}
```